# from where to download resnet50.h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got the following error when trying to load a ResNet50 model. Where should I download the `resnet50.h5` file?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drlng\Desktop\image-captioning-keras-resnet-main\app.py", line 61, in <module>
    resnet = load_model('resnet.h5')
  File "C:\Users\drlng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 211, in load_model
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\drlng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 111, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError("SavedModel file does not exist at: %s/{%s|%s}" %
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: resnet.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for pre-trained weights of ResNet-50, you can find it [here](https://www.kaggle.com/keras/resnet50)

Answer (score 1):

I use [resnet50.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py) for making my model
and read weight of resnet50 from below link:

[weights best](https://github.com/sumitbinnani/Dog-Breed-Classifier/tree/master/saved_models)!

you can download pre train models
It works well